# Install two versions of a lightswitch app

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am struggling to find a way to install two different versions, ones a test connected to a test database and other is the live version. I can publish them with two different applications names but they still have the same assembly name so they cannot both be installed at the same time.

I have a wpf application which I do the same kind of thing with and it works fine because there is a option to change the assembly name in the application properties.

Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can edit the assembly name by editing the .lsproj and csproj files by hand... Good luck

Comment: i changed the assembly name in the desktop client project but still get the same error

Comment: I'd ask a new question. I've sinced moved on from lightswitch apps.  Maybe post a link here in to avoid xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Here's the question, any future readers... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245122/two-versions-of-lightswitch-desktop-application