# Two versions of lightswitch desktop application

Tags: c#, lightswitch-2013

I have deployed a lightswitch application that is being used in a production environment.  I recently made some changes and need to publish a separate copy installed alongside the original for testing purposes.

I tried to look at this video[1](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/04/22/clickonce-installing-multiple-versions-concurrently/) on installing click-once applications side by side, but Lightswitch doesn't have the same options that a normal C# application has.

I edited the assembly name in the desktop client project but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is right, but I managed to get it to install by editing the application deployment manifest.  This file is generated when you publish the desktop client.

So the steps I tried

1. Edit the desktop client project file to change the assembly name in
   my source
2. Edit the published application manifest so the assemblyIdentity name matches

Again, I have no idea what i'm doing so if anyone knows better please tell me.  Screenshot of the manifest tag i edited below.

[image: edit the manifest]

Comment: The settings that are in "normal" projects that you would need to change just end up changing how the manifest is generated, so updating the manifest directly should work.